# How to read and write to a text file in C++?

Tags: c++

Hey everyone, I have just started to learn C++ and I wanted to know how to read and write to a text file. I have seen many examples but they have all been hard to understand/follow and they have all varied. I was hoping that someone here could help. I am a total beginner so I need clear instructions. Here is an example of what i'm trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
string usreq, usr, yn, usrenter;
int start ()
{
    cout << "Welcome..."
int main ()
{
    cout << "Is this your first time using TEST" << endl;
    cin >> yn;
    if (yn == "y")
        {
            ofstream iusrfile;
            ofstream ousrfile;
            iusrfile.open("usrfile.txt", "w");
            iusrfile >> usr;
            cout << iusrfile;
            iusrfile.close();
            cout << "Please type your Username. \n";
            cin >> usrenter;
            if (usrenter == usr)
            {
            start ();
            }
        }
    else
        {
            cout << "THAT IS NOT A REGISTERED USERNAME.";
        }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Which C++ book are you learning from?

Answer (score 47):

Header files needed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
```

declare input file stream:

```
ifstream in("in.txt");
```

declare output file stream:

```
ofstream out("out.txt");
```

if you want to use variable for a file name, instead of hardcoding it, use this:

```
string file_name = "my_file.txt";
ifstream in2(file_name.c_str());
```

reading from file into variables (assume file has 2 int variables in):

```
int num1,num2;
in >> num1 >> num2;
```

or, reading a line a time from file:

```
string line;
while(getline(in,line)){
//do something with the line
}
```

write variables back to the file:

```
out << num1 << num2;
```

close the files:

```
in.close();
out.close();
```

Answer (score 5):

Default c++ mechanism for file IO is called streams.
Streams can be of three flavors: input, output and inputoutput.
Input streams act like sources of data. To read data from an input stream you use `>>` operator:

```
istream >> my_variable; //This code will read a value from stream into your variable.
```

Operator `>>` acts different for different types. If in the example above `my_variable` was an int, then a number will be read from the strem, if `my_variable` was a string, then a word would be read, etc.
You can read more then one value from the stream by writing `istream >> a >> b >> c;` where a, b and c would be your variables.

Output streams act like sink to which you can write your data. To write your data to a stream, use `<<` operator.

```
ostream << my_variable; //This code will write a value from your variable into stream.
```

As with input streams, you can write several values to the stream by writing something like this:

```
ostream << a << b << c;
```

Obviously inputoutput streams can act as both.

In your code sample you use `cout` and `cin` stream objects.
`cout` stands for console-output and cin for `console-input`. Those are predefined streams for interacting with default console.

To interact with files, you need to use `ifstream` and `ofstream` types.
Similar to `cin` and `cout`, `ifstream` stands for `input-file-stream` and `ofstream` stands for `output-file-stream`.

Your code might look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int start()
{
    cout << "Welcome...";

    // do fancy stuff

    return 0;
}

int main ()
{
    string usreq, usr, yn, usrenter;

    cout << "Is this your first time using TEST" << endl;
    cin >> yn;
    if (yn == "y")
    {
        ifstream iusrfile;
        ofstream ousrfile;
        iusrfile.open("usrfile.txt");
        iusrfile >> usr;
        cout << iusrfile; // I'm not sure what are you trying to do here, perhaps print iusrfile contents?
        iusrfile.close();
        cout << "Please type your Username. \n";
        cin >> usrenter;
        if (usrenter == usr)
        {
            start ();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "THAT IS NOT A REGISTERED USERNAME.";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For further reading you might want to look at [c++ I/O reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/)

Answer (score 2):

To read you should create an instance of ifsteam and not ofstream.

```
ifstream iusrfile;
```

You should open the file in read mode.

```
iusrfile.open("usrfile.txt", ifstream::in);
```

Also this statement is not correct.

```
cout<<iusrfile;
```

If you are trying to print the data you read from the file you should do:

```
cout<<usr;
```

You can read more about ifstream and its API [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream)

Comment: ifstreams are always opened in input mode

Comment: I agree that there is no need to pass the mode as ifstream::in is default parameter to the ifstream::open, but I think its a good idea to explicitly mention it.

Comment: Oh yeah whoops, "ofstream iusrfile" was supposed to be "ifstream iusrfile". And thanks for the help on the cout statement.