# C++ read text file from command line ... send create .txt with responding info

Tags: c++

sorry im real new to c++ and can't seem to understand the basic concept of reading a txt file and writing one.  i have a program that currently just prompts the users and then delivers the output on the command line after reading the data.  but i want to have it read a file, and the create a file with its output

heres it so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout << "Enter number of names \n";
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    string * namesArray = new string[a];
    for( int i=0; i<a; i++) {
        string temp;
        cin >> temp;
        namesArray[i] = temp;
    }

    for( int j=0; j<a; j++) {
        cout << "hello " << namesArray[j] << "\n";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks to all..

Comment: This thread tells you how to do txt file read and write in C++:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051865/how-to-read-and-write-to-a-text-file-in-c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string fileName = "test.txt";        
    //declare a file object
    //options are:
    //ofstream for output
    //ifstream for input
    //fstream for both
    fstream myFile;
    //cannot pass a c++ string as filename so we convert it to a "c string"
    //... by calling strings c_str member function (aka method)
    //the fstream::out part opens the file for writing
    myFile.open(fileName.c_str(), fstream::out);
    //add the text to the file end the line (optional)
    myFile << "Some text" << endl;
    myFile.close();//always close your files (bad things happen otherwise)
    //open the file for reading with fstream::in
    myFile.open(fileName.c_str(), fstream::in);
    string myString;
    //get a line from a file (must be open for reading)
    getline(myFile,myString);
    myFile.close();//always close your file
    //demonstrates that it works
    cout << myString;
}
```

Comment: also to append to a file (add to the end) `fstream::app` and for good programming habits it's good to check that the file is open by checking it like this `( myFile.is_good() ){//read or write from the file}else{cout << "Couldn't open file";}`

Answer (score 1):

[This a sample of reading a file](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/8388/) or [This example to write to a file](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) to do what you are asking, if you want to know what are you doing, the << and >> operators, are like water valve that let you move the stream of information from side to side, "cin" is a "data generator", from keyboard, in the example in the page, "myReadFile.open" make a "data generator" from an input file, and you move that data using >> to save it to a string and << to move it to cout, dont know if it help you understand a little more of C++ streams...

Answer (score 1):

```
ifstream input;
input.open("inputfile.txt");
input >> var;  //stores the text in the file to an int or string
input.close();

ofstream output;
output.open("outputfile.txt"); //creates this output file
output << var;  //writes var to the output file
output.close();
```

hope that helps