# Reading from file inserting values into ints and chars C++

Tags: c++, iostream, ifstream

I wanted to read the short binaries from an external file with the key.

> 3 A 0100 3 E 0101 3 G 0110 3 M 0111 3 N 1010 3 H 1011 2 S 100 1 T 00 2
> 10 2 I 111

3 is in an int called pos

A is in a char called al

0100 is in an array called bin etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read and write to a text file in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051865/how-to-read-and-write-to-a-text-file-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your file, read the file data line by line and extract what you need from the line.

```
  std::string line;
  ifstream read;
  //open data files     
  read.open(file_name);
  if(read.is_open())
    cout << "File ./" << file_name << " is open.\n";
  else {
    cout << "Error opening " << file_name << ".\n";
    exit(0);
    }

    while (std::getline(read, line))
    {
    // line =3 A 0100 3 E 0101 3 G 0110 3 ...     
     std::istringstream iss (std::move(line));
     std::string val_str, al, bin; 
        while(! iss.str().empty())
        {
            try{
                iss>>val_str;               
                int val= std::stoi(val_str);     //val = 3 in the first run of the while loop
                iss >> al;               //al = A  in the first run of the while loop
                iss >> bin
                // you can use val, al ,bin
            }catch(..){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```